# Multiple content type support for nodejs XML <-> JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js, content-type

I want to support both XML and JSON Content-Type for all the Rest API request to my server. Any thoughts on it?

I am thinking of adding middleware to check for the request's `Content-Type` / `Accept` and if its XML convert it into JSON and pass it to routes, and make sure that those responses are converted back in to XML before sending.

So my question is:

- What is the optimal way of doing it?
- Are there any exisiting libraries that does this?

I dont want to add addtional logic in each of the end points nor create new end points for it. Theres got to be a better way of doing this.

PS:I am using express.

EDIT: Requirements changed and I am not doing only one way translation (json to xm) using: [this] (http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/)

Comment: There is HTTP `Accept` header…

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) to determine whether the client prefers JSON or XML as opposed to a query parameter. The semantics are the `Accept` header means "I would prefer to receive the following MIME types" and is only used on requests. The `Content-Type` header means "this message body is formatted in this MIME type" and can be used on responses and requests (when their is a message body). I would use this pattern:

- During most of your route handlers, assemble the canonical response data representation as `res.body`. This should just be plain javascript object data. Call `next()` when done.
- Add a middleware after the router that looks for an unsent response with `res.body` set, then based on the `Accept` header, formats `res.body` as XML or just does `res.send(res.body)` if the client wants JSON. You may be able to use the `res.headerSent` boolean to test whether the response is sent, or just make sure that `res.body` gets unset when sent.

Comment: How would you check for the unsent response? And is there a library to convert back and forth?

Comment: BTW POST requests do have 'Content-Type'

Comment: @Hadesara All requests does not containt `Content-Type`

Comment: @Hadesara I'm not going to answer your "are there existing libraries" question. That is a research question you are capable of answering yourself.

Comment: @PeterLyons, I haven't been able to find any library that does a two way conversion (in nodejs/javascript world). Hence, posted here. This is a forum to exchange knowledge.